# How should I best store these files?

Tags: hadoop, nosql, cassandra, hbase

I have a set of image files, they are generally very small, between 5k and 100k.  They can be any size though, upwards of 50mb but this is very rare.  When these images are put into the system they are not ever modified.  There is about 50 TB of these images total.  They are currently chunked and stored in BLOBs in Oracle, but we want to change this since it requires special software to extract them.

These images are access sometimes at a rate of over 100 requests per second among about 10 servers.

I'm thinking about Hadoop or Cassandra, but I really don't know which would be best or how best to index them.

Comment: http://nbonvin.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/apache-vs-nginx-vs-varnish-vs-gwan/

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/219620/which-is-the-best-webserver-for-serving-static-content-and-load-balancing

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would suggest you to have a look at HBase as well. Folks at [Imageshack](http://imageshack.us/) are using HBase for storing their image content and they were able to do it successfully. See this [thread](http://apache-hbase.679495.n3.nabble.com/Storing-images-in-Hbase-td4036184.html).

Coming back to your original question, you could store images which are not very big(~10MB) into Cassandra. And the files which are big can be dumped into the HDFS with a pointer in Cassandra(or HBase).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to serve them to the internet I suggest just putting them on Amazon S3. It will save you a lot of operations overhead, the storage is cheap enough, and you can put a CDN on top of it (CloudFront) if you need. Just use a random ID for each image, use that as file name, and just save that file name in your database (Cassandra could be a good choice there).

In the end it depends on what you're going to do with the images. You should update your question and explain a bit more about your use case. If you're only storing the pictures, maybe you don't need a database at all, but if the images will be served to the internet hundreds of times per second you need something else entirely.